# Nodejs multer express display a file to client after form upload

Tags: node.js, express, upload, display, multer

I'm trying to display a video file with the tools(listed in the title)in after a form submission:

```
const 

 express = require('express'),
 server = express(),
 // SERVER MODULE/DEPENDENCY

 multer = require("multer"),
 // UPLOAD DEPENDENCY

 fs = require('fs'),
 // FOR THE VIDEO UPLOADS  

 PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000,
 //USE AUTO ASSIGNED HEROKU PORT or 3000 for local. DO NOT REMOVE PROCESS.ENV.PORT

 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 //NEEDED FOR OUTSIDE JSON REQUESTS

 _ = require('underscore'),
 //FOR FILTERING OBJECTS AND OTHER TYPES OF DATA

 storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req, file, callback){
           callback(null, './video_uploads');    
    },

    filename: function(req, file, callback){
           callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    } 
 });
 // Video Upload on Multer Dependency 

const upload = multer({ storage: storage}).single('video_upload');


server.use(bodyParser.json()); 
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  // 




 server.post('/register.html', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/register.html');
});


server.post('/video_upload', function(req, res){
 upload(req, res, function(err){
    if(err){
        return res.end('Error uploading file.');
    }

    else{
        res.sendFile('req.file');
    }

    res.end(); 

 });  
});
```

The upload works fine, but im trying to figure out how to send the uploaded file 
back to the front-end right after the upload.

I have a

```
    "<div id="resume-video-player"></div>"
```

that I want to fill in from the client side once the upload is done to automatically play the uploaded video. Do I need communication with Jquery or socket.io to do some communication here? I tried experimenting with res.sendfile as you see there but all i got was a err failed to load resource connection refused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The complete url of your video is

```
var url="PATH"+req.file.filename
```

send this to your client use

```
res.json(url)
```

and in your video tag set src to url with jQuery